# Ask for hint of an inequality

Tags: inequality

$(1+x^2y+x^4y^2)^3\le(1+x^3+x^6)^2(1+y^3+y^6)$ for any $x,y>0$.

I have no idea about it. could you please give me some hint. I'm not requesting the whole proof, a piece of hint or direction to start up is enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hint: [Hölder's inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H%C3%B6lder%27s_inequality#Counting_measure). ${}$

Comment: I got it, Thank you very much. I will post the full answer in a minute. It's a pity I can't upvote you.

Comment: @user58842, Glad to help :)

Comment: upvote, Thank you! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Hölder's inequality:
$|\mathbf{x}\cdot\mathbf{y}|\le\|\mathbf{x}\|_p\|\mathbf{y}\|_q$ where $\mathbf{x},\mathbf{y}\in\mathbb{R}^n$, $p,q>0$ and satisfy $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$.

Taking $\mathbf{x}=(1,x^2,x^4),\mathbf{y}=(1,y,y^2), p=\frac{3}{2}, q=3$, we get the inequality.